# ¿Cómo seleccionar desde model_has_roles de Spatie en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, spatie

En una vista estoy mostrando a todos los usuarios junto a un botón editar, para poder modificar su rol en pantalla.

Pero no sé cómo traer los datos desde la tabla **model_has_roles** a la vista para posteriormente editar el id.

**model_has_roles**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que veo, model_has_roles no tiene un modelo como tal.
Lo he estado intentado hacer diferentes formas en mi controlador.

```
public function userShow($id)
    {   
        $myuser = User::findOrFail($id);
        $roles = DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('role_id', $id)->get();
        return view('content.view.viewuser', compact('myuser', 'roles'));
    }
```

Pero al final en la vista para poder editar al usuario me aparece el error **Property [role_id] does not exist on this collection instance.** al imprimir con **{{ $roles->role_id  }}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando `with` puedes obtener los roles asignados al usuario, este paquete de Spatie te crea una relación llamada `roles` puedes obtener los roles asignados de esta manera:

```
$user=User::with(['roles'])->findOrFail($id);
$roles=$user['roles'];
```

Para poder editar los roles utilizando el paquete de Spatie puedes utilizar el método `syncRoles`:

```
$user->syncRoles(['Rol']);
```

Esto lo que hace es sincronizar los roles al usuario con el que uses este método, es decir si tu usuario tiene un rol asignado, por ejemplo: 'Admin', pero quieres editarle el rol a 'Usuario', usas este método para quitar los roles anteriores y agregar los nuevos.

Si quieres obtener todos los roles, puedes hacerlo con esta consulta:

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
$roles=Role::get()->pluck('name');
```

Un ejemplo del código para obtener todos los roles que estén en la BD y todos los roles del usuario seria este:

```html
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

public function userShow($id)
{   
    $user=User::with(['roles'])->findOrFail($id);
    $roles=Role::get()->pluck('name');
    return view('content.view.viewuser', compact('user', 'roles'));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me queda más claro.
¿Pero cómo imprimo en la vista el rol del usuario?

Porque me da el error Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance cuando utilizo {{ $roles->name }} o similar.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la relación roles trae un arreglo de objetos, es decir, aunque solo hayas asignado un rol a tu usuarios para acceder a el debes usar arreglos, por ejemplo {{ $user['roles'][0]->name }}